# Should we point out unrelated possible improvements to the question, in our answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

Imagine there is a question, with code in it, asks for a specific problem. Besides, its code is in bad practice. For example:

```
if (obj.exist()) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

while it can be as simple as:

```
return obj.exist();
```

It's not related to the question. But it surely can be improved.

We should include solution for the problem in our answer, sure. But should we also point out the possible improvements in its code?

Comment: Yes, absolutely, just make sure it doesn't distract from your answer. If it's something really small though, I usually just leave a comment on the question.

Comment: For this kind of thing, I would post a comment to suggest the improvement.